# Match in pairs from Object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object in javascript like this:

```
Object {1-name: "Count", 1-value: "10", 2-name: "Colour", 2-value: "Red"}
```

I want to make from it key-value array, something like this:

```
array[Count] = 10
array[Colour] = "Red"
```

How can I match pairs from this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var a  = {"1-name": "Count", "1-value": "10", "2-name": "Colour", "2-value": "Red"};

var allkeys = Object.keys(a);
var namekeys = [];var valuekeys = [];
allkeys.forEach( function(value) {  
   if (value.indexOf( "name" ) != -1)
   { 
      namekeys.push( value ) 
   } 
   else
   { 
     valuekeys.push( value ); 
   }
 });
valuekeys.sort();
namekeys.sort();
var array = {};
for ( var counter = 0; counter < namekeys.length; counter++)
{
   array [ a[ namekeys[ counter ] ] ] = a[ valuekeys[ counter ] ] ;
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define your object properly

```
var obj = {Count: 1, Colour: "Red"};
```

Now you can access like an array to it. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1k2xfbo/

Comment: The question is asking how to transform an *existing* object into that format, where the key names are (presumably) not known in advance.

Comment: Then he can iterate over the object to get the object's fields name

Answer (score 0):

This proposal collects all names and values, and builds later the wanted object with the key/value pairs.

```js
var object = { '1-name': "Count", '1-value': "10", '2-name': "Colour", '2-value': "Red" },
    result = function (o) {
        var r = {}, t = [];
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            var p = k.split('-');
            t[p[0]] = t[p[0]] || {};
            t[p[0]][p[1]] = o[k];
        });
        t.forEach(function (a) {
            r[a.name] = a.value;
        });
        return r;
    }(object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Another approach, taking the count of the numbers are always beginning with one and half of the properties as length, then a `for` loop will do:

```js
var object = { '1-name': "Count", '1-value': "10", '2-name': "Colour", '2-value': "Red" },
    result = function (o) {
        var i,
            l = Object.keys(o).length / 2,
            r = {};;
        for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
            r[o[i + '-name']] = o[i + '-value'];
        }
        return r;
    }(object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have 'associative' arrays, but you can deal with objects in your case.
Solution with `Array.map` and `String.split` functions:

```
var obj = {'1-name': "Count", '1-value': "10", '2-name': "Colour", '2-value': "Red"};
var prop, arr = [];

for (prop in obj) {
    if (prop.indexOf("name") !== -1) {
        arr[parseInt(prop.split("-")[0])] = obj[prop];
    }
    if (prop.indexOf("value") !== -1) {
        arr[parseInt(prop.split("-")[0])] += ':'+ obj[prop];
    }
}

arr = arr.map(function(v){
    var obj_parts = v.split(":"), obj = {};
    obj[obj_parts[0]] = obj_parts[1];
    return obj;

})

console.log(arr);
// the output: [{Count: "10"}, {Colour: "Red"}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zm3w4pvc/